# Сделать View не закргуленным внутри закругленного View

Tags: javascript, react-native

Хочу сделать вот такую форму у View как на скриншоте[image: Скриншот]
Но у меня не получается сделать зеленый блок без закругления. В чем проблема?

```
 <View style={{ overflow: 'hidden', height: '90%', width: '100%', position: 'absolute', bottom: 0, borderTopLeftRadius: 370, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
       <View style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 200, overflow: 'hidden', borderRadius: 0, left: 0, marginTop: 70, width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'green'}}/>
  </View>
```

[image: то что у меня]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А может попробовать двинуть фигуру за пределы экрана влево просто?

В CSS вроде как-то так: `left: -20px;`

Upd:

CSS

```
<div class="round">
</div>
```

HTML

```
.round {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  position: absolute;
  border-top-left-radius: 500pt;
  left: -20px;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Результат выглядит примерно так, как вы хотели. Может у вас получится адаптировать под свой синтаксис.

Comment: Фигура сдвигается, но загругляется все равно

Comment: @olliJes, обновил ответ. Прикрепил пример.